# How to write plist file to non-simulator path?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I'm developing an iOS app in Swift, and I'd like to write an `NSArray` to a `.plist` file in a sensible location, such as `~/Documents/file.plist`.

However, when I do this...

```
var path = "~/Documents/file.plist".stringByExpandingTildeInPath
var result = array.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
if (result) {
    println("The file was successfully written to '\(path)'")
}
```

...the value of `result` is true, but this awful monstrosity is printed in the Xcode console:

```
The file was successfully written to '/Users/dan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/605701BC-06E7-48BB-9B7A-2EFD04C7DC12/data/Containers/Data/Application/1DA58E4F-ED2D-4216-8E3C-76AB80B9C160/file.plist'
```

Is there a way to tell Xcode to write to the *actual* location I specified?

Comment: There is no such path in iOS devices/or not accessible, then why you want to do that ?

Comment: The path `/Users/dan/Documents/file.plist` also doesn't exist in iOS, and yet if I explicitly use that path, the iOS simulator writes to that location. However, this doesn't help other developers whose name is something other than Dan.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this.

```
var result = array.writeToFile("file.plist", atomically: true)
```

Comment: So where will that file go then? What is the absolute path?

Comment: To the documentray folder. Different from OS X, IOS uses sandbox for each application. Only few folder you can get accessed into including the cache folder and documentray folder.